# "Кыш", "брысь": происхождение слов

Tags: этимология

Интересно, как появились такие восклицания, как "кыш", "брысь" и т.д.? Во всех языках они разные. Но это просто взятый от балды возглас или там есть какие-то осмысленное происхождение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словарь Фасмера: "кыш" = "кш, кш" (звуки, которыми прогоняют овец) см. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/42258/кш
  Есть еще "шу" ( отсюда и "шугать") - значение "пугать птиц"

Википедия:   "кыш" этимологически от тюркского kış (окрик, которым отгоняют птиц).

Я так понимаю, что все эти слова изначально звукоподражательные. Употребляются с общим значением "прогнать кого-либо". Чаще применительно к животным, птицам, насекомым. Реже (разг. пребрежительное) к людям.

Answer (score 1):

КШ, КЫШ - не звукоподражательное "междометие" для изгнания, отгона кого-л., а тюркское слово, производное от глаголов:

качыр- (ойрот. алтайск.), қашыр- (каз.) – «гнать, прогнать; обращать в бегство»;
качу (тат.), кач- (ойрот. алтайск.), қаш- (каз.), kaç(mak) [кач(мак)] (тур.), qaç(maq) [кач(мак)] (азер.) – «бежать, мчаться; убегать, обращаться в бегство, сбежать; удирать, удрать; скрываться, скрыться, перен. дезертировать / уклоняться от работы»;
koş(mak) [кош(мак)] (тур.) – «бежать, мчаться, скакать, спешить, торопиться».

Ср. kaçak [качак] (тур.), качак (тат.), қашақ (каз.) – «беглый, беглец, бежавший»; Ср. казаки – «беглый, свободный люд» (по Карамзину).

koşu [кощю] (тур.) – «бег, состязание в беге, пробег; скачки»; koşucu [кощюджю] (тур.) – «участник состязания в бегах, бегун»;
hız [хыз] (тур.) - «скорость, спешка».

В этом же семантическом поле:
...[kaš] (шумер.) – «быстро бежать»;
[kas, каш] (санскр.) – «бежать; двигаться»;
caccia [качча] (ит.) – «охота (прежде всего верховая)»; cacciare [каччаре] (ит.), caçar [качар] (порт.), cazar [касар] (исп.), kaċċa (мальт.), chacier (арх. фр.), chasse [шасс] (фр.), chase [чейс] (англ.) – «гнаться за кем.-л., преследовать».

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, ничего не знаю в отношении овец... Но вот если наблюдать за обычными домашними кошками, то можно заметить: кошка, увидевшая врага, громко и протяжно произносит: "Кшшшш" или "Пшшшш". Смысл этого "слова", в переводе с кошачьего - "Уйди, а то нападу!" Если испуг был резким, внезапным, звучит другое "слово" - короткое, отрывистое мягкое "Пшть!" А кошка, с которой случилась досадная неприятность - например, она встала в лужу или её чем-то облили, - произносит: "Брррр" - обычно с потряхиванием головой или лапкой. Поэтому все эти слова - "Кыш", "Пшить", "Брысь" - вполне могут быть звукоподражаниями с общим смыслом: "Уходи, иначе с тобой произойдут неприятности".

Answer (score 0):

Русское «брысь» очень похоже на праславянский глагол *brysati, который в русском языке не сохранился. Возможно, это его повелительная форма. Можно, например, сравнить с парой «бросать» и «брось» (от *brъsati, который явно родственен *brysati). Но это всего лишь моя гипотеза.

Comment: Почему же Вы не сказали, что значит глагол *brysati? Мне Ваша версия показалась довольно любопытной, пока я не посмотрел значение этого слова — чистить, вытирать и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Всё конечно интересно, но банально, ш-с - шипение, р - рычание. Два животных звука для акцентирования опасности, которые в целом воспринимают почти все животные на генетическом уровне - собаки рычат, кошки шипят. С "б" проще зайти на раскатистую "р", а с "к" проще перейти на "ш". Так что я не думаю, что в этом какой-то великий смысл, просто этот набор звуков оказался удачным. А кричать на незнакомых животных словами, думаю мало у кого в голову придёт.

Так что смысла нет, просто удачные заходы на Р-Сь и Ш.

Лошадям кричат "Но", "Ну", "Тррр" и "Тпру" - думаю, никто не станет искать великий смысл слова "тпру".

А еще кошкам у нас говорят "кис-кис" - и они отзываются. Потому что они с детства слышат этот кис-кис, а вот на востоке кошки на кис-кис не реагируют.

И с большой долей вероятности, что если вы скажете: быс-быс или мыс-мыс - кошка отреагирует точно также, как на кис-кис.

Так что нет разницы какие априорные команды произносить, главное, чтобы это делали примерно всё и часто, и чтобы звуки были наиболее легкослышимые для животных - с, ш, р.